# Can't install libdb4.8 and libdb4.8+++ on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: package-management, kubuntu, 19.04

Recently I reinstalled my system (Kubuntu 19.04) but I can't install those two libraries (I have the same system on my laptop and there's no issue there). The error message:

```
Package libdb4.8-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libdb4.8-dev' has no installation candidate
```

I tried to search for an answer but didn't find a satisfying one. I tried to compile it myself but got an error because of name ambiguity in a header file. I have added Bitcoin PPA to my system.

Answer (score 0):

The package is not available as the source and binaries were removed from the Ubuntu archive during Trusty development. They were obsolete in Ubuntu and Debian.

[image: db4.8 publishing history]

Comment: I managed to download them like 1 month ago on my laptop.

Comment: Those never existed in 19.04 archive, so they must have come from somewhere else.